# Does lsblk always list disks in sorted ascending order?

Tags: linux, rhel, filesystems

Does `lsblk` always list disks in ascending order (each device letter increasing by one ) and sorted?

For example:

```
lsblk | awk '{print $1}'
NAME
fd0
sda
├─sda1
└─sda2
├─vg00-lv_root
├─vg00-lv_swap
└─vg00-lv_var
sdb
sdc
sdd
sde
sdf
sdg
sdh
sdi
sdj
sdk
```

**We do not want to get it like the examples below**

Example of non ordered disk list (output edited for the example )

```
lsblk | awk '{print $1}'
NAME
fd0
sda
├─sda1
└─sda2
├─vg00-lv_root
├─vg00-lv_swap
└─vg00-lv_var
sdb
sdc
sdd
sde
sdi
sdj
sdk
sdf
sdg
sdh
```

Example of disks starting with `sdd` instead of `sdb` (again, edited for the example )

```
lsblk | awk '{print $1}'
NAME
fd0
sda
├─sda1
└─sda2
├─vg00-lv_root
├─vg00-lv_swap
└─vg00-lv_var
sdd
sde
sdf
sdg
sdh
sdi
sdj
sdk
sdl
sdm
```

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: because I use it in my bash script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `lsblk(1)` manual page:

> The default output, as well as the default output from options like `--fs` and `--topology`, is subject to change. So whenever possible, you should avoid using default outputs in your scripts. Always explicitly define expected columns by using `--output columns-list` in environments where a stable output is required.

If you require the output to be sorted, I'd suggest using the `-o` (output columns) and `-x` (sort column) options. Use `lsblk --help` to get a list of the column names.

For example:

```
lsblk -o NAME -x NAME
```